# Detecting if rectangles (buttons) overlap on x or y axis

Tags: algorithm, rectangles, collision

I am currently trying to develop a prototype in android where the user is able to drag 4 separate buttons around the screen.

The trouble I am having is with collision detection. If one of the buttons is alongside another, for example, only movement along the Y axis should be permitted. Similarly, if one of the buttons is touching the top or bottom of another button, only movement along the X axis should be allowed.

Something like

```
for (TouchButton t:myButtons)
{
  if(!(t.equals(b)))
  {
   if((b.getY() >= t.getY() && (b.getY() <= (t.getY() + t.getMeasuredHeight()))))
   {
       if((b.getX() >= t.getX() && (b.getX() <= (t.getX() + t.getMeasuredWidth()))))
       {
           //dont move
       }
   }
}
```

should be able to detect if the buttons are touching across both axis? But how do I determine if it should then be possible to slide up or across the object?

[image: Example]

Comment: How about finding the minimum amount of movement that you have to do to make it no longer overlap?

Comment: ???The objects never overlap. But with the current solution as soon as the objects touch they the moving button will not be permitted to move along either the X or Y axis. I need to be able to allow movement but only along the axis

Comment: Yes -- I mean you calculate how much they would overlap if you did the regular movement, and then make the minimal adjustment in X or Y to make them not overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK adapting some code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754722/detecting-if-rectangles-buttons-overlap-on-x-or-y-axis/18756547?noredirect=1#18756547), I have come up with a solution which works perfectly:

```
Float newX = ev.getX() - (b.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
Float newY = ev.getY() - (b.getMeasuredHeight()/2);


for (TouchButton t:myButtons)
{
    if(!(t.equals(b)))
    {
        Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle(t.getX(), t.getY(), (float)t.getMeasuredWidth(), (float)t.getMeasuredHeight());
        Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(newX, b.getY(), (float)b.getMeasuredWidth(), (float) b.getMeasuredHeight());
        Rectangle r3 = new Rectangle(b.getX(), newY, (float)b.getMeasuredWidth(), (float) b.getMeasuredHeight());

        if(r1.interects(r2))
        {
            MoveX = false;
        }
        if(r1.interects(r3))
        {
            MoveY = false;
        }

    }
}
```

and here is Rectangle.java:

```
public class Rectangle 
{

    private Float startX;
    private Float startY;
    private Float width;
    private Float height;
    private Float endX;
    private Float endY;

    public Rectangle(Float _x, Float _y, Float _width, Float _height) 
    {
        startX = _x;
        startY = _y;
        width = _width;
        height = _height;
        endX = _width + _x;
        endY = _height + _y;
    }



    public Float getX()
    {
        return startX;
    }

    public Float getY()
    {
        return startY;
    }

    public float getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }

    public float getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }

    public float getEndX()
    {
        return endX;
    }

    public float getEndY()
    {
        return endY;
    }

    public boolean interects (Rectangle _r2)
    {
        return rectOverlap(this, _r2);
    }

    private boolean valueInRange(float value, float min, float max)
    { return (value >= min) && (value <= max); }

    private boolean rectOverlap(Rectangle A, Rectangle B)
    {
        boolean xOverlap = valueInRange(A.getX(), B.getX(), B.getEndX()) ||
                        valueInRange(B.getX(), A.getX(), A.getEndX());

        boolean yOverlap = valueInRange(A.getY(), B.getY(), B.getEndY()) ||
                        valueInRange(B.getY(), A.getY(), A.getY() + B.getHeight());

        return xOverlap && yOverlap;
    }
}
```

[old choppy answer here]

[for historical purposes]

I'm not sure how elegant this is, maybe somebody can come up with something better?

Building on Khaled A Khunaifer's answer, I've realized I need to check where the buttons WOULD be placed if the move was to take place, then only perform each move if there would be no collisions after:

```
Boolean MoveX = true;
Boolean MoveY = true;
Float newX = ev.getX() - (b.getMeasuredWidth()/2);
Float newY = ev.getY() - (b.getMeasuredHeight()/2);


for (TouchButton t:myButtons)
{
    if(!(t.equals(b)))
    {
        if (areOverlapping(t,b.getX(), newY))
        {
            MoveY=false;
        }
        if(areOverlapping(t,newX,b.getY()))
        {
            MoveX = false;
        }

    }
}

if (MoveX)
{
    b.setX(newX);
}
if (MoveY)
{
    b.setY(newY);
}



boolean areOverlapping (TouchButton a, double x, double y)
{
    return (y >= a.getY()
        && (y <= (a.getY() + a.getMeasuredHeight()))
        && x >= a.getX()
        && (x <= (a.getX() + a.getMeasuredWidth())));
}
```

This kind of achieves what I'm looking for but it's a bit choppy and sometimes allows the buttons to overlap. I'll try experimenting with the areTouching but I need to decode the logic first as the way it's written is producing errors.

Answer (score 3):

This is the strict version:

```
boolean areOverlapping (TouchButton a, TouchButton b)
{
    return (b.getY() >= a.getY()
        && (b.getY() <= (a.getY() + a.getMeasuredHeight()))
        && b.getX() >= a.getX()
        && (b.getX() <= (a.getX() + a.getMeasuredWidth()))));
}
```

In this version, touching by axis is allowed:

```
boolean areOverlappingButTouchIsAllowed (TouchButton a, TouchButton b)
{
    return (b.getY() > a.getY()
        && (b.getY() < (a.getY() + a.getMeasuredHeight()))
        && b.getX() > a.getX()
        && (b.getX() < (a.getX() + a.getMeasuredWidth()))));
}
```

Also you can check if they touch:

```
boolean areTouching (TouchButton a, TouchButton b)
{
    return ((b.getY() == (a.getY() + a.getMeasuredHeight()))
        || (a.getY() == (b.getY() + b.getMeasuredHeight()))
        || (b.getX() == (a.getX() + a.getMeasuredWidth())))
        || (a.getX() == (b.getX() + b.getMeasuredWidth()))));
}
```

then

```
for (TouchButton t : myButtons)
{
    if (!t.equals(b))
    {
         if (areOverlappingButTouchIsAllowed(b,t))
         {
             // overlapping beside borders
         }
         else if (areTouching(b,t))
         {
             // touching; overlapping borders only
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok I guess I've not been clear enough with my description. I've added a diagram to help explain what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @LairdPleng you can use `areTouching(a,b) && !areOverlappingButTouchIsAllowed(b,t)` function to check if 2 buttons are touching

Comment: Khaled your areTouching method doesn't compile, I'm afraid :(

Comment: @LairdPleng this is because this is a psudo-code .. I was using the functions you mentioned; use functions that are suitable to your context of developement

Comment: Khaled... the function names are not the issue. Your logic/math is wrong... the brackets are in the wrong places. I don't understand what you're trying to achieve so I can't fix it! Anyway I have created a solution that works, no problem.

Comment: If you don't understand basic geometry, don't say my math is wrong .. how can you judge what you don't know? also this is basic logic, where I tried all possible combinations of interlacing

Comment: Simple... copy and paste your areTouching() routine into a project. Create a random touchbutton object with getX, getY, getMeasuredWidth, and getMeasuredHeight functions which return 0. Now try and compile the code.... it doesn't work! Somewhere along the lines you have too many or too few ||s or (s or )s...

Comment: I fixed areTouching() .. but what's funny in this question is that you gave us no technology framework to consider when testing this code .. these codes are Java, are you working in Java Applet or Android App ?

Answer (score 1):

1. For checking whether button on boundary.

Keep 4 value's corresponding to the distance to the boundaries along +x, -x, +y, -y..
When one of these values gets zero further movement should be restricted..

1. each button goes from X1 to X2 and Y1 to Y2 on the X-Y axis. Keep this for all buttons..If your button is moving along X axis, check whether it will overlap with any other buttons X interval.. If so, calculate Y distance to that button. If zero, restrict movement. otherwise let it move..